# PowerShell - "Write-Output" vs "return" in functions

Tags: powershell, syntax, psobject, pscustomobject

I've been using PowerShell for a number of years, and I thought I had a handle on some of its more 'eccentric' behaviour, but I've hit an issue I can't make head nor tail of...

I've always used "return" to return values from functions, but recently I thought I'd have a look at Write-Output as an alternative. However, PowerShell being PowerShell, I've found something that doesn't seem to make sense (to me, at least):

```
function Invoke-X{ write-output @{ "aaa" = "bbb" } };
function Invoke-Y{ return @{ "aaa" = "bbb" } };

$x = Invoke-X;
$y = Invoke-Y;

write-host $x.GetType().FullName
write-host $y.GetType().FullName

write-host ($x -is [hashtable])
write-host ($y -is [hashtable])

write-host ($x -is [pscustomobject])
write-host ($y -is [pscustomobject])
```

output:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable
System.Collections.Hashtable
True
True
True
False
```

What is the difference between $x and $y (or 'write-output' and 'return') that means they're both hashtables, but only one of them '-is' a pscustomobject? And is there a generalised way I can determine the difference from code, other than obviously checking whether every hashtable I have in a variable is also a pscustomobject)?

My $PSVersionTable looks like this, in case this behaviour is specific to a particular version of PowerShell:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.492
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.492
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Cheers,

M

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`return` and `[pscustomobject]` are red herrings here, in a way.

What it comes down to is:

- Implicit *expression* output vs. *cmdlet*-produced output; using `return` (without a cmdlet call) falls into the former category, using `Write-Output` into the latter.
- Output objects getting *wrapped* in - mostly invisible - `[psobject]` instances only in *cmdlet*-produced output.

```bash
# Expression output: NO [psobject] wrapper:
@{ "aaa" = "bbb" } -is [psobject] # -> $False

# Cmdlet-produced output: [psobject]-wrapped
(Write-Output @{ "aaa" = "bbb" }) -is [psobject]  # -> $True
```

Note that - surprisingly - `[pscustomobject]` is the same as `[psobject]`: they both refer to type `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]`, which is the *normally invisible helper type* that PowerShell uses behind the scenes.
(To add to the confusion, there *is* a separate `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` type.)

For the most part, this extra `[psobject]` wrapper is benign - it mostly behaves as the wrapped object would directly - but there are instances where it causes subtly different behavior (see below).

---

> And is there a generalised way I can determine the difference from code, other than obviously checking whether every hashtable I have in a variable is also a pscustomobject

Note that a hashtable is *not* a PS custom object - it only appears that way for - any -  `[psobject]`-wrapped object due to `[pscustomobject]` being the same as `[psobject]`.

To detect a true PS custom object - created with `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` or `New-Object PSCustomObject` / `New-Object PSObject` or produced by cmdlets such as `Select-Object` and `Import-Csv` - use:

```bash
$obj -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] # NOT just [pscustomobject]!
```

Note that using the related `-as` operator with a true PS custom object is broken as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.1.0 - see below.

As an example of a situation where the extra `[psobject]` wrapper is benign, you can still test even a wrapped object for its type directly:

```bash
(Write-Output @{ "aaa" = "bbb" }) -is [hashtable]  # $True
```

That is, despite the wrapper, `-is` still recognizes the *wrapped* type.
Therefore, somewhat paradoxically, *both* `-is [psobject]` and `-is [hashtable]` return `$True` in this case, even though these types are unrelated.

---

*There is no good reason for these discrepancies* and they strike me as leaky abstractions (implementations): internal constructs accidentally peeking from behind the curtain.

The following **GitHub issues** discuss these behaviors:

- [Objects are situationally invisibly `[psobject]`-wrapped, sometimes causing unexpected behavior.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579)
- [Why is `[pscustomobject]` the same as `[psobject]`, even though a distinct `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` type exists?](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4344)
- [Should all `[psobject]` cmdlet parameters be changed to `[object]`?](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5551)
- [The `-as` operator does not recognize `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` instances as such](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4343).

Comment: Amazing - thanks for the comprehensive answer. I was semi-aware of PowerShell's wrappers but this explains the 'oddness' I was seeing. In my case I've changed ```$x -is [pscustomobject]``` to ```$x -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]``` and it's behaving how I expected it to now.

Comment: This  explanation is 1k points worthy.  I was struggling on why Write-Host (std output) was being taken as a function return. So now its clear the two alternatives for writing functions: Implicit vs cmd-let output. Amazing!

Comment: I'm glad to hear the answer is helpful, @LeonardoT; perhaps it was just a typo, but note that the distinction is between implicit expression output on the one hand and `Write-Output` on the other, not `Write-Host` - the latter _bypasses_ the success output stream (the PowerShell equivalent of stdout) and writes directly to the host (console) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58826180/45375). The short of it is that explicit use of `Write-Output` is rarely necessary - _implicit_ output is not only more concise but also faster.

Comment: An other difference is that return ends the function: `function Invoke-X{ write-output "output"; return "return" }` (returns array with `output` and `return`) vs `function Invoke-Y{ return "return"; write-output "output" }` (returns the string `return`)

Comment: @sschoof Yes, `return` is a flow-control statement that unconditionally exits the enclosing function or script block or script - see [about_Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return). `return <some-command-or-expression>` is just syntactic sugar for `<some-command-or-expression>; return`.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that adding `Write-Output` debug messages, unlike .net, will change the return type to an array. Adding write lines can break functions.

```
function Invoke-X {
    $o1 = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1, 2 }
    return $o1
}

function Invoke-Y {

    $o1 = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1, 2 }
    Write-Output "Debug messageY"
    return $o1
 }

function Invoke-Z {
    $o1 = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1, 2 }
    Write-Output "Debug messageZ"
    return ,$o1
 }

$x = Invoke-X;
$y = Invoke-Y;
$z = Invoke-Z;

Write-Host
Write-Host "X  Type: " $x.GetType().FullName $x.foo
Write-Host
Write-Host "Y  Type: " $y.GetType().FullName
Write-Host "Y0 Type: " $y[0].GetType().FullName $y[0]
Write-Host "Y1 Type: " $y[1].GetType().FullName $y[1].foo
Write-Host
Write-Host "Z  Type: " $z.GetType().FullName
Write-Host "Z0 Type: " $z[0].GetType().FullName $z[0]
Write-Host "Z1 Type: " $z[1].GetType().FullName $z[1].foo
```

Gives:

```
X  Type:  System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject 1 2
Y  Type:  System.Object[]
Y0 Type:  System.String Debug messageY
Y1 Type:  System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject 1 2
Z  Type:  System.Object[]
Z0 Type:  System.String Debug messageZ
Z1 Type:  System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject 1 2
```

Comment: If you want to write debug messages you’re better off using ```Write-Debug``` or ```Write-Host```, whereas *by design* ```Write-Output``` sends values to the pipeline (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.1) which effectively means it becomes part of the return value(s) from the function.