# "$xyz" and "Write-Host "$xyz"" giving different output

Tags: powershell, compareobject, write-host, get-filehash

I am hashing all the files in one location, an origin folder, and writing the hashes to a variable and then doing the same to all the files in another location, a destination folder:

```
$origin = Get-ChildItem .\Test1 | Get-FileHash | Format-Table -Property Hash -HideTableHeaders
$destination = Get-ChildItem .\Test2 | Get-FileHash | Format-Table -Property Hash -HideTableHeaders
```

Then I am comparing them with Compare-Object like so:

```
Compare-Object $origin $destination
```

Now in my test I purposefully have deviations, so when the above code returned no differences I knew I had a problem.

Then I found out that if I do the following, that the hash values arn't there:

```
PS> Write-Host "$origin"
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

However, if I just type the following and press enter, then the hash values are present (like I want):

```
PS> $origin

6B86B273FF34FCE19D6B804EFF5A3F5747ADA4EAA22F1D49C01E52DDB7875B4B
D4735E3A265E16EEE03F59718B9B5D03019C07D8B6C51F90DA3A666EEC13AB35
4E07408562BEDB8B60CE05C1DECFE3AD16B72230967DE01F640B7E4729B49FCE
```

I am assuming when I use `Compare-Object`, that my variables are not presenting the hash values like I expected.

Does anyone know what is going on or have any recommendations?  This is being used to ensure files are moved from an origin location to a destination location (this is one check in a script I'm working on).  I am keeping this purely PowerShell, which means no `xcopy` or `robocopy`.

Comment: Leave out the `Format-Table` because that is only for outputting the stuff in a certain way on console.

Comment: Specify `Compare-Object $origin.Hash $destination.Hash`. Otherwise, the variables are hash-tables which are identical. At least I assume so.

Comment: `$xyz` is short for `write-output $xyz`.

Comment: @Alex_P: Actually, reference types (in the absence of `-Property`) are compared by their `.ToString()` values, and in the case at hand that would invariably yield string `'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileHashInfo'` (the full type name only, irrespective of property values), which indeed would cause all objects to be considered equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re use of `Format-Table` to create the input collections for `Compare-Object`:

**Only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets for *display formatting*; never use them if data must be *programmatically processed***.

`Format-*` cmdlets output *formatting instructions*, not *data* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375).

Therefore:

- *Omit* the `Format-Table` calls from your input-collection definition commands:

```
$origin=Get-ChildItem .\Test1 | Get-FileHash
$destination=Get-ChildItem .\Test2 | Get-FileHash
```

- Then pass the *names of the properties* to compare the objects by to `Compare-Object`:

```
Compare-Object $origin $destination -Property Path, Hash
```

Note the need to compare by *both* path and hash, to make sure that only files of the same name are compared.

As an aside: If you *didn't* specify `-Property`, the objects would by default be compared by their `.ToString()` value - and since the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileHashInfo` instances output by `Get-FileHash` only ever stringify to that very *type name* (irrespective of their specific property values), no differences would be found.

---

As for `$origin` vs. `Write-Host $orgin`:

- **Just executing `$origin` is implicitly like executing `Write-Output $origin` - it writes to the *success output stream*** (see [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)), which *by default* goes to the console.

  - Success output that goes to the console is **automatically formatted by PowerShell's rich [output-formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml)**.
- **`Write-Host`**, by contrast, **serves a *different purpose* than `Write-Output`**:

  - It writes *directly to the console*<sup>[1]</sup>, *bypassing* PowerShell's success output stream and thereby also its usual formatting. **Its primary purpose is to *write status messages, interactive prompt messages, ... to the display* - as opposed to *outputting data*.**
  - **`Write-Host` *itself* applies output formatting**, but only by **simple `.ToString()` stringification**, which often yields unhelpful (type name-only) representations, as in your case.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45829541/45375) for more information about the differences between `Write-Output` and `Write-Host`.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, since PowerShell version 5, `Write-Host` output reaches the console via the *information* output stream (number `6`), but its primary purpose is still to *write to the display* as opposed to *outputting data*.</sup>